# Find the least residue modulo 7 of the quantity $22 × 51 + 698^5$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the least residue modulo 7 of the quantity $22 \times 51 + 698^5$

- Based off the examples from class, here is what I have thus far:

$22 \times 51 + 698^5 \pmod{7}$

- The 22 becomes a 1 because $3 \times 7$ is 21 with one as a remainder
- The 51 becomes a 2 because $7 \times 7$ is 49 with two as a remainder

Giving me $1 \times 2 \times 698^5 \pmod{7}$

- Am I on the right track and how would I handle the $698^5$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are doing fine. Now $698 = 99 \cdot 7 + 5$, but if you write it as $-2$, it is easier to compute $(-2)^{5} = -32 = (-5) \cdot 7 + 3$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, would this then leave me with 1 × 2 + 3, giving me 5 (mod 7) as the final answer?

Comment: Perfect, that's it!

Comment: Notice that in final paragraph the addition of $698^5$ got switched to multiplication.